# How to add a textBox Column in ASP.net Code.behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

From the Code-Behind is there a way to Add a DataTable Column as a TextBox? In the aspx File I add a textbox column with:

```
<asp.TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="myfield" runat="server" Columns="6" />
...
```

But I need to do it in the code-behind, something like:

```
Dim dt As new DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity",Type.GetType("System.Int32"), TextBox)
```

Comment: A 'DataTable' is in memory only and does not have text boxes.

Comment: You cannot store `DataTable` as `TextBox` object with column type of `Integer`. You need to use `Convert.ToInt32(myfield.Text)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use [`DataTable.Columns.Add()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) with 3 parameters like this:

```
Public DataColumn Add(ByVal columnName As String, ByVal type As Type, ByVal expression As String)
```

Since the third expression is a `String`, you cannot use [`TextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.7.2) object from `System.Web.UI.WebControls` to add into that column. However, you can add `Integer` value from textbox `Text` property into `DataRowCollection` using row index and column name in code-behind:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
' declare other 5 columns first
' assume 'Quantity' is the 6th column (index 5)
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity",Type.GetType("System.Int32"))

' example to fill first row (index 0)
' Convert.ToInt32 or Integer.TryParse may be used too
dt(0)("Quantity") = Integer.Parse(myfield.Text)
```